# Issues creating a jfreechart score bar/chart

Tags: java, pdf, jfreechart

I am trying to create a score/percent/status bar using jfreechart. 
The image show what it's suppose to look like.[Good ScoreChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj7xl.png)

It looks like one bar from a stack chart, so I try to adjust from there. (Do let me know if there is a better way to do this other than the stack chart)

I am seeing multiple issues doing the bar this way. I can't make the start line and end line longer. I can't put text on top of both start/end line.(I think they get chopped off) I cannot put center text in the middle of the bar either...
Here is what I got now. [Bad ScoreChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0V5X.png)

Here is the code for the bad Chart.

```
public JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(null, null, null, dataset,
        PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, false, false, false);

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);

    CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    ((BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer()).setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
    plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, DONUT_CHART_ORANGE);
    plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, DONUT_CHART_BLUE);


    ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setVisible(false);

    CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();

    domainAxis.setVisible(false);
    plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
    plot.setOutlineVisible(false);

    CategoryItemRenderer renderer = ((CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot()).getRenderer();    
    //renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new CustomItemLabelGenerator());    
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
    ItemLabelPosition position = new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER);
    renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(position);

    Marker startMarker = new ValueMarker(0);
    startMarker.setPaint(Color.black);
    startMarker.setLabel("000000000");
    startMarker.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));

    startMarker.setLabelOffset( new RectangleInsets(UnitType.ABSOLUTE, 10,0,0,0));
    startMarker.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.TOP_RIGHT) ;
    startMarker.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.BASELINE_CENTER);     

    plot.addRangeMarker(startMarker);        

    Marker endMarker = new ValueMarker(1000);
    endMarker.setPaint(Color.black);
    endMarker.setLabel("1000");
    endMarker.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
    endMarker.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.TOP);
    endMarker.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_RIGHT);     
    plot.addRangeMarker(endMarker);     

    RectangleInsets chartRectangle = new RectangleInsets(35, 0, 35, 0);
    chart.setPadding(chartRectangle);

    return chart;
}


public CategoryDataset createDataset() {
    double inValue = 775;
    double[][] data = new double[][] {
        { inValue }, 
        { 1000- inValue }, 
    };
    return DatasetUtilities.createCategoryDataset("A", "B", data);
}
```

Any Idea how to move the text so they show up on top of the lines and at the center of the bar?
Can we adjust the line width at the beginning and the end?

Thanks for any idea/info.